# Going back to the last frame when pressing the 'back' button on android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I've got an AIR app with 30 frames. The user can navigate in the app but I'd like to add a function that allows him to press the "back" button on Android devices. When he'll do that, he will go back to the frame he was (NOT `prevFrame` but the frame he was).

Example, the user is on frame 25. Then goes to frame 12. If he clicks on the back button, he will go back to frame 25.

I've managed to activate the back button for Android :

```
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeypress, false, 0, true);

    function checkKeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
    //So, what should I put here for going back to the last frame viewed ? 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should have a variable that hold the desired position ( in your case the last frame of the user ) and when the button is pressed just gotoAndStop to it

Answer (score 0):

save the last frame in a variable

```
function checkKeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
gotoAndStop(lastFrame)
}
}
```

Comment: so, in each frame at the beginning, I have to put : `lastFrame = currentFrame` ? The problem would be that last Frame would be = to the current frame so won't go back.

Comment: You wouldn't change lastFrame to equal the currentFrame until right before the frame gets changed. For example if you're changing the frame to nextFrame, your code would look like, lastFrame = currentFrame; currentFrame = nextFrame; gotoAndStop(nextFrame);